# Function scope inside var

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to access the variables email and password inside the function createLocalAccount, how can I do this maintaining the code structure?

```
var createLocalAccount = function(response) {
    return localDb.put('login', {
        uid: response.uid,
        email: email,
        password: password
    });
};

this.createAccount = function(firstName, lastName, email, password) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    createAccount(email, password)
        .then(createLocalAccount);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass it to the function:

```
var createLocalAccount = function(email, password, response) {
    return localDb.put('login', {
        uid: response.uid,
        email: email,
        password: password
    });
};

this.createAccount = function(firstName, lastName, email, password) {
    return createAccount(email, password)
        .then(function(response) {
            return createLocalAccount(email, password, response);
        });
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `deferred` and simply return the Promise that calling `createAccount().then()` returns.